# nmblookup doesn't work if I have my firewall enabled

Tags: networking, samba

I've opened TCP ports 137, 138, 139 and 445 on the server, and yet unless I disable the firewall, running `nmblookup server_name` fails.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed the problem by opening ports 135 and 136 in addition to the ones mentioned. Also I opened them on UDP as well as TCP.